# Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I got a problem when analyzing my code below :

```
NSDate *formatterDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:smBook.time_limit];
formatterDate = [formatterDate initWithTimeInterval:1*24*60*60 sinceDate:formatterDate];
```

The message is : Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller .

Can anyone tell me the reason why ?

Comment: We need more code, and we need to know whether you're using ARC, Garbage Collection, or manual Reference Counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below line:

```
formatterDate = [formatterDate initWithTimeInterval:1*24*60*60 sinceDate:formatterDate];
```

with this line:

```
NSDate *newDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:1*24*60*60 sinceDate:formatterDate];
```

Release this newDate when you are doe with your operations.

Comment: Please tell me how can I accept it ... Sorry , I'm a newbie .

Comment: You will find a "TRUE" mark, near by the answer. Clicking on it, it will convert to Green sign. So, it will help others also. And it will give 15 points to me..!

Comment: Ok , I clicked it . Thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the message not occurring from the above line please check the whole class in or enable zombie objects from edit schemes of your project